# Show slide-in banner only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-cookies

The below function brings in a slide-in banner when the user has scrolled past the element with the ID of `#last`.

The banner has a `.close` button. But once the banner was closed and the user navigates away and back the banner shows up again.

How do I modify the code so the browser remembers the banner was closed and not show it again? (until the cookies are cleared)

Thanks.

The banner is implemented as shown below on this website: [bps-world.com](https://www.bps-world.com/)

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var distanceTop = $('#last').offset().top - $(window).height();

        if  ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
            $('#slidebox').animate({'right':'0px'},300);
        else
            $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px'},100);
    });

    $('#slidebox .close').bind('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Does it have to be cookies?  IMO, using local storage or session storage would be an easier/cleaner solution.  If it does have to be a cookie, you should take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery) protected StackOverflow.

Comment: It doesn't matter. As long as once the close button is clicked the banner doesn't show up again

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
var slided = localStorage.getItem("slided");
  console.log(slided);
if(!slided) {
  console.log("i'm here");
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    var distanceTop = $('#last').offset().top - $(window).height();
    if(!slided) {
      if($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop) {
        $('#slidebox').animate({'right':'0px'},300);
        localStorage.setItem("slided",true);
        slided = true;
     }else
        $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px'},100);
     }

 });

 $('#slidebox .close').bind('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
 });
}
});
```

You can use localStorage to store information about slide appeared already.
Then you are reading it .

For the future I would even not register scroll event listener if there is stored information that slide has appeared already.

I have fixed the code with missing set up variable. [codePen here](http://codepen.io/kejt/pen/vgpZGa?editors=1011)

Comment: I don't think your solution ever sets the localStorage item.

Comment: Any new ideas? Your solution makes the banner nor show up at all.

Comment: I have updated code and gave you codePen to take a look :))

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var sliderVersion = 1;  // iterate this if you need to force the slider to be open (even if the user has closed it in the past)
    var sliderVersionFromLocalStorage = localStorage.get('sliderVersion');  // get the cached slider version from localStorage

    if (sliderVersionFromLocalStorage === null || sliderVersionFromLocalStorage === undefined || sliderVersionFromLocalStorage < sliderVersion) {  // if the user hasn't yet closed the current slider version, then launch it

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var distanceTop = $('#last').offset().top - $(window).height();

            if  ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
                $('#slidebox').animate({'right':'0px'},300);
            else
                $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px'},100);
        });

        $('#slidebox .close').bind('click',function(){ 
            $(this).parent().remove();
            localStorage.set('sliderVersion', sliderVersion); // once the user closes the slider, we update the cached slider version so it won't open again
        });

    }

});
```

The above code allows you set the `sliderVersion` number on [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) when closing the slider-- this will prevent it from opening again for the user unless you increment the slider version in your code.

Alternately, if you only want the browser to remember the user closed the slider for the duration of the session (rather than for all time or until you increment the slider version) you can also leverage [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) which uses a similar API to `localStorage` but only persists as long as the browser is open-- if they close their browser and reopen, `sessionStorage` will be cleared.

Comment: Now the banner doesn't show up at all. I have your code on [this page](https://www.bps-world.com/)

Comment: thanks, but still not working. The banner doesn't show up at all. It's implemented here: (https://www.bps-world.com/)